# Set Page Color to No Color when Forwarding or Replying in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

Is it possible to automatically clear out the page color of a message in Outlook 2010 when replying or forwarding an email?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that either your theme is turned off or if you have a theme the background image is unchecked.

```
File > Options > Mail > Compose Messages > Stationary and Fonts > Theme
```

OR... you could always send in plain text.

```
File > Options > Mail > Compose Messages > Plain Text
```

[image: Outlook 2010 Options Dialog]