# Automatically (VBA) remove page colour when replying or forwarding email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, colors, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am looking to create a macro to remove the page colour from an email when replying to it or forwarding it, either automatically on the single click of a button, instead of having to go to the setting on the ribbon, which takes a few clicks. This is because often an advertising e-shot has a very dark background, and when forwarded the format of the new text is hard or impossible to read.  (Besides I am a staunch opposer of Outlook "stationery", and will remove it wherever possible!)

This thread asks the same question [Set Page Color to No Color when Forwarding or Replying in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/346616/set-page-color-to-no-color-when-forwarding-or-replying-in-outlook-2010) but it doesn't seem to have been answered.  There are one or two other instances in the internet where the question has been asked, but again, no solution.

Surely it must be simple....I assume there must be a property that needs switching?

P.S. I'm thinking that this will involve manipulating the HTML code for the body, and isn't actually a mail-item property - Am I correct?  If so, how can this be done (reliably) in VBA

Comment: What have you tried? Any VBA [change events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx)? Any rules? Anything?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).